# Evaluate $\lim_{x \to 0}(2-e^{-1})^{\cot x}$

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x \to 0}(2-e^{-1})^{\cot x}$$

Hello, I've been trying to solve this. I think that I should use MacLaurin formulas. I've got $(1 + x)$ in the brackets, but still can't simplify ${\cot x}$, because $(\frac{1}{x} - \frac{x}{3} + o(x))$ gives division by zero.

Comment: Hint: what is $\lim_{x\to\infty} a^x$ ?   BTW : you don't get "division by zero", you are not evaluating at $x=0$, but $x\to 0$

Comment: @leonbloy it depens on the value of $a$:
1) $0 < a < 1$ lim = 0 
2) $a = 1$ \lim = 1 
3) $a > 1$ \lim = +\infty

Comment: How big is $(2-\frac 1e)$ and where is going $\cot(x)$ when $x\to 0$ ?

Comment: @Denis. correct. Now,  see that that's precisely your case. $2-e^{-1}=a$ is just a number, and the exponent goes to infinity.

Comment: You should use both - if they differ, then the limit does not exist. See Jan Eerland's answer

Comment: I understood that I made a mistake. It was actually $e^{x}$, not $e^{-1}$. But thanks for your help anyway, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Well, first of all: a two-sided limit does not exist!

To find the limit from the left and right, use the fact that $\left(2-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{x}$ is a continous function of $x$.

---

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\left(2-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\cot(x)}=\left(2-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\lim_{x\to 0^-}\cot(x)}=\left(2-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{-\infty}=0$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\left(2-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\cot(x)}=\left(2-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\lim_{x\to 0^+}\cot(x)}=\left(2-\frac{1}{e}\right)^{\infty}=\infty$$

---

---

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(2-e^x)^{\cot(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp\left(\ln\left((2-e^x)^{\cot(x)}\right)\right)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}\exp(\cot(x)\ln(2-e^x))=\exp(\lim_{x\to 0}\cot(x)\ln(2-e^x))=\exp(-1)=e^{-1}=\frac{1}{e}$$

Comment: Sorry for confusion. It was actually $e^{x}$. However, I will leave it as is.

Comment: @Denis so $-1$ has to be $x$?

Comment: Yes, exactly so.

Comment: @Denis, Look to my edit, did this answer the question?